# linking with two version of icu

Tags: gcc, icu

I tried to create simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/usr/local/icu/include/unicode/ustring.h"

UChar*
u_strdup(const UChar *in)
{
    uint32_t len = u_strlen(in) + 1;
    UChar *result = malloc(sizeof(UChar) * len);
    if (!result)
        return NULL;
    u_memcpy(result, in, len);
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

when i compile with

```
gcc test1.c -o tes1 `/usr/local/icu/bin/icu-config --ldflags`

/tmp/cc5h5bjr.o: In function `u_strdup':
test1.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `u_strlen_50'
test1.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `u_memcpy_50'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

as you can see, compiler still use the old version of icu

icu version:

- 50.1.2 (old, system)
- 60.2 (new)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

change your compile line to

```
gcc test1.c -o tes1 `/usr/local/icu/bin/icu-config --ldflags --cppflags`
```

and use `#include <unicode/ustring.h>`